# remove Site Spaces from Confluence dashboard

Tags: confluence

How can I delete the `Site Spaces` tab as part of the Confluence dashboard? I'm using the [Subspace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.communardo.confluence.plugins.subspace) add-on and have no use for that ever growing flat list of spaces.

UPDATE: I'm using the latest Confluence version 5.x what ever exactly that is. The [Subspace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.communardo.confluence.plugins.subspace) add-on offers a hierarchical view of all Spaces so I don't need the default flat view that doesn't scale well and bloats the Confluence Dashboard page.

Comment: Do you want to know how to display something else in its place, or are you simply trying to remove the spaces list from the dashboard?

Comment: Also, do you know which version of confluence you are using? It might be slightly different depending on the version, but it shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would edit the dashboard macros in Confluence version 4.3.something, I think it's more or less the exact same process in version 5:

First, access the site administration page by going to "Edit" -> "Administration" -> "Site Administration"

Once you're on the site administration page, look for the "Add-ons" section of the left hand menu. There should be a "Manage Add-ons" link under that section, click it.

Now you'll want to scroll down to the "System Plugins" section. You'll need to click the "Show System Plugins" link in order to have these add-ons displayed. These add-ons are not displayed automatically because changing them can seriously impact the functionality of certain parts of confluence. Be careful here to not change anything you didn't intend to, and make sure you can undo any changes you do intend to make. I would recommend having the dashboard page open in another browser window or tab so you can refresh it without leaving the "Manage Add-ons" page. This way, if you accidentally change or remove something fatal, you can revert any changes without a great deal of trouble.

Once the system plugins list is displayed, scroll down until you see the "Dashboard Macros" item. Click that, and then, depending on your settings, you will either have to choose "Manage Plugin Modules" or you will simply have to expand a list of modules which are enabled. From here, you can find the modules you want to disable and do so. For instance, you could simply disable the "Popular Tab" module to remove that from the updates list, or you could choose the "spaces-list" module to remove the long list of all site spaces. Once you've made the changes you want, be sure to refresh the dashboard page to check the impact you've had before closing the administration page. When you're finished, drop administration access to avoid unintentionally breaking something down the road.

Here's a link to some general information about customising the dashboard in 4.3:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF43/Customising+the+Dashboard

and here's a link to the same basic info for version 5:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Customising+the+Confluence+Dashboard

I hope that helps.